# How to get access to current tree node inside grammar?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

The question is about how to get access to current tree node inside `{"action"}` block in the grammar.

I'm talking about `Java` target, so inside generated rule-method I'd like to gain access to object `root_1` (see below, standard generated code, `SUBJECT` here is the token inside my grammar, it doesn't matter):

```
  {
    Object root_1 = (Object)adaptor.nil();
    root_1 = (Object)adaptor.becomeRoot((Object)adaptor.create(SUBJECT, "SUBJECT"), root_1);
    adaptor.addChild(root_1, stream_noun.nextTree());
    adaptor.addChild(root_0, root_1);
  }
```

Inside grammar I'd like to have an ability to do something like:

```
subject :   noun -> ^(SUBJECT noun) { ... place code here to work with `root_1` object ... } ;
```

Could somebody suggest any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found some *ugly* method. I can get an access to mentioned `root_1` object, using `@after` construction, and gaining access to `root_0` object:

```
subject
@after{
    // ...((CommonTree)root_0).getChild(0)... - this is `root_1` object.
}
    :   noun -> ^( SUBJECT noun);
```

But if somebody will suggest more appropriate method - it will be welcomed.

**UPD:** as dear [280z28](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138304/280z28) mentioned, this one `((CommonTree)root_0)` could be replaced with `$tree` with set `options{ASTLabelType=CommonTree;}`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the `$tree` property.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. But as I see, `$tree` is just the reference to variable `root_0`. It also could be placed only in `@after` construction (before that it contains just `null` value). So, my question is still opened, because I'm looking for handsome way how to get reference to `root_1` variable.

Comment: Furthermore, as `$tree` is actually `retval.tree = root_0`, it also must be cast to `CommonTree` type.

Comment: @Andremoniy you need to set the `options{ASTLabelType=CommonTree;}` option for `$tree` to be that type.

Comment: That changes things, thanks. I think, that our answers must be mixed for full picture.